# VBA Check if a decimal value has only 2 decimal points. Error using Int()

Tags: vba, excel, int

I'm using vba to write some check routines on a Excel file. One of them need to check if the values of some cells have only 2 or less decimal points. To do that, i write a function that basically have this code:

```
Function checkValues(sheet as Worksheet) as Boolean
    val = sheet.Cells(1,1).Value
    val = val * 100
    valInt = Int(val)

    if valInt <> val then
        checkValues = false
        Exit Function
    end if
    checkValues = true
End Function
```

The problem is that when i put the value of the Cell(1,1) equal to 1,12 this function returns False. When i use the Debug i see clearly that both valInt and val are equal to 112, but i don't know why the statement 'valInt <> val' gives me 'True'.

Anybody can help me?

ps: i already try to change to Fix() function and try a lot of others statements.

Thanks very much.

Comment: I had to declare val as double and valint as Long but it works for me.  Try `.Value2` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Double precision numbers cannot represent decimal values exactly (unless that decimal value can be expressed as the sum of some powers of 2, e.g. `0.75` is exact because it is `2^-1 + 2^-2`).  Try using `val = CDec(val) * 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double precision numbers cannot represent decimal values exactly (unless that decimal value can be expressed as the sum of some powers of 2, e.g. `0.75` is exact because it is `2^-1 + 2^-2`).  So use a variable type of `Variant/Decimal` rather than `Variant/Double`:

```
Function checkValues(Sheet As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim val1 As Variant ' Allows a subtype of Variant/Decimal
    Dim valInt As Long
    val1 = CDec(Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Value) * 100
    valInt = Int(val1)

    If valInt <> val1 Then
        checkValues = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    checkValues = True
End Function
```